# Adding more http/2 connections in a grpc channel

Tags: asp.net, go, grpc, http2, grpc-go

There's a property called `SocketsHttpHandler.EnableMultipleHttp2Connections` in `ASP.NET`'s grpc library which enables a channel to create additional http/2 connections when the concurrent stream limit is reached. Is there anything available in Go which could help me achieve the same?
In grpc-go library's documentation, there's no details of how to create grpc channels also.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour,I recommend taking the tour, as well as reading how to ask a good question and what's on topic.

Answer (score 0):

There's no existing API in gRPC-Go for the same functionality.
The closest you can do is to make a resolver or balancer to create multiple connections. But it won't know about the stream limit.

Documentations and examples are available in the repo:

- https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples
- https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/Documentation